# Don't load default dags on docker-compose

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

For do not load default DAGS, I edited the files airflow.cfg of the containers: airflow-scheduler_1,airflow-webserver_1 and airflow-worker_1. After editing each of them, i made `db reset`. Unfortunately the default dags are always there.
DO you how to do that ?

`docker-compose ps`

```
airflow-init_1        /bin/bash -c function ver( ...   Exit 0                                                             
airflow-scheduler_1   /usr/bin/dumb-init -- /ent ...   Up (unhealthy)   8080/tcp                                          
airflow-triggerer_1   /usr/bin/dumb-init -- /ent ...   Up (unhealthy)   8080/tcp                                          
airflow-webserver_1   /usr/bin/dumb-init -- /ent ...   Up (healthy)     0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp,:::8080->8080/tcp          
airflow-worker_1      /usr/bin/dumb-init -- /ent ...   Up (unhealthy)   8080/tcp                                          
flower_1              /usr/bin/dumb-init -- /ent ...   Up (healthy)     0.0
.0.0:5555->5555/tcp,:::5555->5555/tcp, 8080/tcp
postgres_1            docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up (healthy)     5432/tcp                                          
redis_1               docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up (healthy)     6379/tcp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [docker-compose.yaml](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.1/docker-compose.yaml) file, there's a line

`AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'`

where you should change `'true'` to `'false'`. After that, the default example DAGs will not be loaded.

Comment: I made the change and refresh the page, all the default DAGs still presents.

Comment: You probably need to check again how Docker works. The yaml file is not dynamically read so refreshing the webserver won't suffice.

Comment: okey thank you. I just down and up the docker-compose and it's work fine.